# Unity UI - Make text come out and go back in

Tags: unity, unity-ui, text-mesh-pro

In Unity UI I have a TextMeshPro Button and some TextMeshPro Text like in the following image:
[image]

Is there any function in a Tween Library like DOTween that could make the text look like its coming out from the left side then going back in? (not scaling). Or without a tweening library how could this be done?

Something like:

[image]

As @DMGregory pointed out, this could be understand in two ways

1. coming out and in letter by letter or
2. smooth transition, cutting the letters.

My aim was to achieve 2) - a smooth transition.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but would moving your label and using a [mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Mask.html) be a way to go? There are probably some folks with better approaches that'll chip in.

Comment: To clarify: do you want it to appear and disappear one full letter at a time like in your example diagram? Or should it move smoothly, occasionally cutting off or fading out half a letter as it crosses the threshold between shown and hidden?

Comment: @DMGregory a smooth transition, not letter by letter.

Comment: In that case, move the label and use a mask as Vaillancourt suggested.

Comment: Please share your solution as an Answer, rather than editing it into the bottom of your question. Try to share enough detail that a future reader would be able to solve the problem just from following your example.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help @Vaillancourt , @DMGregory and @Kevin - a mask works perfectly, will tune it further.

How I done it:

1. Create a Panel near the Button
2. Added a Rect Mask 2D as a component on the Panel

Now the children of the Panel (in this case some Text component) will only be visible when they are over the Panel

https://i.imgur.com/gfZjLhz.mp4

To move the text I used a tweening library (DoTween). If anyone is interested how the code of it would look:

```
private void HintSequence()
    {
        DOTween.Sequence()
            .Append(HintsQuestionMarkButton.transform.DOShakePosition(2.0f, 4.0f, 10, 50.0f, false, true))
            .AppendInterval(1.5f)
            .Append(HintsText.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(0, 0.58f), 2.5f, false))
            .AppendInterval(1.5f)
            .Append(HintsText.DOAnchorPos(new Vector2(-170, 0.58f), 2.5f, false))
    }

private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("HintSequence", 2.0f, 25.0f);
    }
```

Final result: https://i.imgur.com/JJ28Q7G.mp4